# How do I actually write "\n\r" to an environment variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have tried command substition, but it replaced '\n' with space

```
$ export GREENIE="$(python -c 'print "\n\r"*4')"
$ echo $GREENIE |hexdump
0000000 200d 200d 200d 0a0d                    
0000008
$
```

All I need is like this:

```
$ echo $GREENIE |hexdump
00000000  0a0d 0a0d 0a0d 0a0d
00000008
$
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You probably want `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend for catching bugs of this kind (unquoted expansions). You'd still have an extra newline from the `echo` after catching what it found for you, but that would have been a smaller set of problems.

Comment: As an aside, by the way -- all-caps variable names are actually in space reserved for variables with meaning to the operating system and shell (which is why the shell itself uses `PS1`, `PATH`, etc). Use lower-case names for your own variables to prevent overwriting a name with meaning to the system by mistake; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (discussing environment variables -- but shell variables share the same namespace: setting a shell variable with the name of an existing environment variable will overwrite the latter).

Comment: btw -- `GREENIE=$'\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r'` will assign the literal string in question to your variable in bash (just a regular shell variable, not an environment variable, until you `export` it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Python one-liner works just fine as-is; the problem is your test. No matter how you set the variable, you won't see its value properly in your hexdump unless you quote its expansion, like this:

```
$ printf '%s' "$GREENIE"  | hexdump
0000000 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d
0000008
```

(I used `printf` instead of `echo` to avoid confusion, since `echo` adds an extra newline on the end, which shows up in the output of `hexdump` even though it's not part of the value of `$GREENIE`. I could also have used `echo -n` since this is a bash-specific question, but I try to avoid that since it's not part of POSIX.)

Without the quotes, the shell does word-splitting on the newlines, so you get nothing but the carriage returns back from `printf`:

```
$ printf '%s' $GREENIE | hexdump
0000000 0d 0d 0d 0d
0000004
```

If you use `echo` instead (with bash's `-n` option to avoid the confusing extra newline), it just joins those carriage-returns back together with the default separator (space):

```
$ echo -n $GREENIE  | hexdump
0000000 0d 20 0d 20 0d 20 0d
0000007
```

You could also use shell built-ins to generate the string, although it doesn't have a convenient string-multiplier operator. You can use a dumb for loop:

```
GREENIE=$(for ((i=0;i<4;++i)); do printf '\n\r'; done)
```

But it's short enough that you can just type it out:

```
GREENIE=$(printf '\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r')
```

If we're being bash-specific, you could use ANSI strings and skip the `printf`:

```
GREENIE=$'\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r'
```

or combine them and get cute with brace-expansion:

```
GREENIE=$(printf '%s' $'\n\r'{,,,})
```

Either way, if you are just using the variable inside a shell script, you don't need to `export` it to the environment; that's only for making it accessible to other programs:

```
$ GREENIE=hello
$ echo $GREENIE
hello
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("GREENIE")'
None
$ export GREENIE
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("GREENIE")'
hello
```

You can also export a variable into the environment of a particular program without setting it in the shell at all, by placing the assignment on the command line where you run the program:

```
$ unset GREENIE
$ echo $GREENIE

$ GREENIE=hello python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("GREENIE")'
hello
$ echo $GREENIE

$
```

And if you're *not* exporting it to the environment, the usual convention is to give it a lowercase name:

```
$ greenie=hello
$ echo $greenie
hello
```